# Can you add a Text box to a report in SSRS that links to an email?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Is there a way to add a text box or button of some kind in a SSRS report where the user clicks it and then it opens an email account for the user to enter any bugs found?
Thanks much for your help.
Moni

Answer (score 3):

This is certainly something that you can do:

1. Add a textbox to a report
2. Right-click on the textbox and select "Text Box Properties"
3. In the resulting window, select "Action"
4. Select "Go to URL"
5. In the "Select URL" text box, enter your email address with mailto: at the front, eg: mailto:abc@abc.com